# Dynamically change html element from c# code through

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have application which support multilingual. Now I have price page which is geo sensitive so that it might be change over location. I am trying to make one template for Html content and changing value from it based on location specific Value. Change value will be append into original html response.

Can somebody help me for such or it is not possible ?

Comment: I don't know how to change html elements via C# but AFAIK you can use a `Literal` control that is empty when not needed and gets filled with additional data on need time.

Comment: @MahdiTahsildari thanks for reply. It is pretty well answer but my confusion is that if I am trying something like adding [Price] in html and change this [Price] through code but is this way HTML support ?

Comment: what about using <asp:label ..

Comment: @AkilVhora take a look at my answer, I think it's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to have access to your html controls inside code behind (C#/VB.net code) you need these two steps:

1.add `runat=server` to your html control definition
2.declare an id for the html control

look at the example below:

**Source**

```
<input runat="server" id="Text1" type="text" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Text1.Value = "Mahdi";
}
```

`Text1` is an html control and `Button1` is a server control, when you click `Button1` the html text controls value changes to "Mahdi".